# Mycelium Backup Restore

Tags: bitcoin-core, cryptography, mycelium-wallet

Is there a way I can restore my mycelium Bitcoin wallet if I have forgotten the 12-word list?

I have searched everywhere and no one describes a situation like this.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No. Do you still have access to Mycelium and can send BTC from there to other addresses? Then you could transfer funds somewhere else. But to restore a wallet e.g. on another phone you need the mnemonic words based on the security implemented to secure wallets (or the extended private key which you probably do have as well).